# jQuery custom events data (subscribe and trigger)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out, how I can set arguments for custom events.
How I can set an argument when I subscribing the event and then add some additional data when I trigger event.

I have a simple JS for testing, but in e parameter of "handle" I see only data of subscribe.

```
function handle(e) {
    //e.data has only "b"
    alert(e.data);
}

function myObj() {
    this.raise = function () {
            //Trigger
        $(this).trigger("custom", { a: "a" });
    }
}

var inst = new myObj();
//Subscribe
$(inst).bind("custom", { b: "b" }, handle);
inst.raise();
```

Comment: Just a hint. Alerting here will give you ```[object Object] also [object Object]```. Using ```console.log(e.data, ' also ', triggerParam)``` will show you the actual objects in your browser console;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameters supplied to `.trigger()` are passed as the second parameter of the event handler function.

```
function handle(e, triggerParam) {
    //e.data has only "b"
    alert(e.data + ' also ' + triggerParam);
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks :) I missed that in jQuery tutorials...Thanks again :)